# Passing parameter using routes laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have two routes

```
Route::get('/fasilitas/{fasilitas_id}/{any}','Fasilitas_controller@detail_fasilitas');
Route::get('/fasilitas/get_kategori/{kf_id}','Fasilitas_controller@get_kategori');
```

but when i access the second routes, it always gets the first routes why?
and how to fix it?
thanks for helping me

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the routes?

Comment: try with changing route order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the `where` method on a route instance. The `where` method accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should be constrained:

```
Route::get('/fasilitas/{fasilitas_id}/{any}','Fasilitas_controller@detail_fasilitas')->where(['fasilitas_id' => '[0-9]+', 'any' => '[0-9]+']);
Route::get('/fasilitas/get_kategori/{kf_id}','Fasilitas_controller@get_kategori')->where('kf_id' => '[0-9]+');
```

For more info [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

**Another way** to pass it define name route.

```
Route::get('/fasilitas/{fasilitas_id}/{any}','Fasilitas_controller@detail_fasilitas')->name('fasilitas.example1');

  <a href="{{ route('fasilitas.example1',['fasilitas_id'=>1,'any'=>2]) }}">

  Route::get('/fasilitas/get_kategori/{kf_id}','Fasilitas_controller@get_kategori')->name('fasilitas.example2');

  <a href="{{ route('fasilitas.example2',['kf_id'=>1]) }}">
```

Comment: Check another way as well for this kind of route.

Answer (score 1):

When hitting `/fasilitas/get_kategori` you trigger the first route, with `get_kategori` being the `{fasilitas_id}`.

Change the order of your routes, so `/fasilitas/get_kategori` gets triggered first:

```
Route::get('/fasilitas/get_kategori/{kf_id}','Fasilitas_controller@get_kategori');
Route::get('/fasilitas/{fasilitas_id}/{any}','Fasilitas_controller@detail_fasilitas');
```

Answer (score 0):

The second segment of the first route is a wildcard, that means it could be anything.

When the second route is called in browser the second segment (/get_kategori/) is passing through the wildcard of the first route.

Changing the route order may solve the problem. But the best practice is changing the route name. Example:

```
Route::get('/fasilitas/something_else/{fasilitas_id}/{any}','Fasilitas_controller@detail_fasilitas');
Route::get('/fasilitas/get_kategori/{kf_id}','Fasilitas_controller@get_kategori');
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but the first routes is a must i can't change that

Answer (score 0):

Try with name . It will be more efficient

Fasilitas ! 

May be you tried to write facilities. 
Whatever, am writing base on ur method.

```
Route::get('/fasilitas/{fasilitas_id}/{any}','Fasilitas_controller@detail_fasilitas')->name('detail.fasilitas');
Route::get('/fasilitas/get_kategori/{kf_id}','Fasilitas_controller@get_kategori')->name('get.kategori');
```

How to call at front page for two parameter and single parater ?
Have a look below .

For detail.fasilitas

```
<a href="{{ route('detail.fasilitas',$fasilitas_id,$any) }}">Detail Fasilitas</a>
```

For Single Parameter : get.kategori

```
<a href="{{ route('get.kategori',$kf_id) }}">Get Kategori</a>
```

Try it.
Let me know its work or not .

**Have fun with code.**